# hibernate-validator strange IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, xml, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am currently fighting a very strange problem. What I basically want to do is to use Bean Validation for validating some (non-JPA) objects. However as the object's classes get generated, I am for the moment stuck with defining the validations with xml.
As it is the reference implementation I use hibernate-validator, added the necessary maven dependencies to the project and made up a simple xml validation mapping and a test.

When the test gets executed, I get an exception

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000123: Unable to parse META-INF/validation.xml.
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.XmlParserHelper.getSchemaVersion(XmlParserHelper.java:112)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:156)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.XmlParserHelper.getSchemaVersion(XmlParserHelper.java:109)
    ... 29 more
```

Interestingly enough, the IOException is thrown in the finally block at XmlParserHelper.getSchemaVersion(...). What's going on here? Which could be the cause for this error? Below are some more informations about the setup.

The validation files are located in src/main/resources/META-INF (validation.xml and constraints.xml) and look as follows:

validation.xml:

```
<validation-config xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration">
    <default-provider>org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator</default-provider>
    <message-interpolator>org.hibernate.validator.engine.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator</message-interpolator>
    <traversable-resolver>org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver</traversable-resolver>
    <constraint-validator-factory>org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl</constraint-validator-factory>
    <constraint-mapping>/constraints.xml</constraint-mapping>
</validation-config>
```

constraints.xml:

```
<constraint-mappings xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.1.xsd">
    <default-package>com.nano</default-package>
    <bean class="Person">
        <field name="familyName">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Size">
                <element name="min">4</element>
            </constraint>
        </field>
    </bean>
</constraint-mappings>
```

The relevant maven dependencies in the project are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

The test in which the exception occurs is a very basic Proof-of-Concept test which does the following:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setFamilienName("x");
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(p);
assertEquals(1, violations);
```

Comment: Is this only happen when you execute tests? What is your setup? How do you call Validator?

Comment: The problem occurs in a very simple proof-of-concept test that really does not really much. I have added the test code to the problem description above.

Comment: Hmm I seem to be the only one with that problem ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Where does this error occur (on which computer setup)? I had the exact same issue using the hibernate validator in one of our projects. On the local computers everything works fine. For the stages we use IBM AIX servers. On the AIX server with the IBM SDK Version 6 I get the same exception:

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000123: Unable to parse META-INF/validation.xml.
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.XmlParserHelper.getSchemaVersion(XmlParserHelper.java:108)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser.parseValidationXml(ValidationXmlParser.java:76)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getBootstrapConfiguration(ConfigurationImpl.java:287)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:361)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:214)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:459)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:156)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:425)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.XmlParserHelper.getSchemaVersion(XmlParserHelper.java:105)
... 35 more
```

Looking into the code at `XmlParserHelper` the following happens:

- The Helper uses a `javax.xml.stream.XmlInputFactory` to create a `javax.xml.stream.XmlEventReader` for the validation.xml-file.
- The reader is used to get the version-attribute of the xml-file.
- Somewhere in the process the stream to the validation.xml-file gets closed, which leads to the exception during the call of `BufferedInputStream.reset()`

Since IBM uses an own StAX 1.0 implementation (XL XP-J 1.1 - see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.doc.user.aix64.60/user/xml/using_xml.html), this should be something implementation specific.

Because of this i tried to change the XmlInputFactory-implementation to see if it works with another one. I was able to reproduce the same exception locally using StAX 1.2 from Codehaus. This implementation uses a `com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory` to create the reader. The `com.bea.xml.stream.reader.XmlReader.read()`-method closes the stream if there is nothing more to read:

```
    /**
 * Reads the number of characters read into the buffer, or -1 on EOF.
 */
public int read(char buf [], int off, int len) throws IOException
{
int val;

if (closed)
    return -1;      // throw new IOException ("closed");
val = in.read (buf, off, len);
if (val == -1)
    close ();
return val;
}
```

It looks like the IBM SDK has a similar behaviour that it closes the stream on reading (and probably you have that in your environment too).

**Solution**: In the end I got it working using an other StAX implementation (the JAXP reference implementation 1.4 - see https://jaxp.java.net/). It also worked with Woodstox. For changing the StAX implementation in your application you have to do the following:

- Add the needed libraries to your classpath
- Create the directories META-INF/services in your application
- Under META-INF/services create the file **javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory**
- Write the full qualified classname of your choosen implementation into this file (e.g. `com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl`)
- When creating the `XmlInputFactory` in the `XmlParserHelper`, the hibernaet validator uses the class defined in this file.